# x64 bit asm in MSVC11 error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, 64-bit

So I have two files in my solution.

test.asm

```
.code
test proc
mov eax, 1
ret
test endp
end
```

and

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

extern "C" int test();

int main()
{
std::cout << "eax = " << test() << std::endl;
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

I have the solution platform set to x64 in the configuration manager and have masm checked in Build Customization. I found two related posts but what was suggested did not help. I was following a video on youtube and did exactly as the author did but I get these errors:

```
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _test referenced in function main
1>C:\Users\omar\Desktop\ASM\x64\Debug\ASM.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Could someone help me to figure out what the problem is? I really want to get into x64 assembly. Thanks

Comment: I don't know about the linker protocol. Maybe in-line asm would be easier - especially just to get started with it. (Just use __asm { mov eax, 1 } inline in your Visual Studio C program).

Comment: @Mark : VC++ does not support inline asm for x64, only for x86.

Answer (score 2):

Your assembler's function name must be `_test` and not just `test`. You can see that in your linker's error message:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _test
                                          /\
                                          ||
right here ---------------------------------
```

For more details see [C name decoration in Microsoft Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C_name_decoration_in_Microsoft_Windows).

Comment: I tried that and I'm still get the same error. Could you post an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Visual studio, you need to add the name of the assembly file to the additional dependancies

1. Right click on the project
2. Go to properties
3. Click on Linker
4. Click on Input
5. In the additional Dependancies, add test

Assuming the assembly code works fine and it is in the same directory as the c++ source file it should work

Comment: An .asm file is not suitable linker input; he need's to link to masm's output object file.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271627/Assembly-Programming-with-Visual-Studio-2010-2012)

Also, I had to use underscores